# How to pass multiple values in react through radio input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

I want to pass the value of the whole row of a table to a function when the radio button in the row is selected. This is the table code

```
<table className="table table-bordered table-stripped">
                <thead>
                    <th>AD Type</th>
                    <th>AD Title</th>
                    <th>Image/Video URL</th>
                    <th>Video Thumbnail</th>
                    <th>Landing URL</th>
                    <th>Placement</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>DSP</th>
                    <th>Select</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        creative.map(
                            creative =>
                            <tr key = {creative.id}>
                                <td>{creative.ad_type}</td>
                                <td>{creative.ad_title}</td>
                                <td>{creative.image_url}</td>
                                <td>{creative.video_thumbnail}</td>
                                <td>{creative.landing_url}</td>
                                <td>{creative.placement}</td>
                                <td>{creative.country}</td>
                                <td>{creative.dsp}</td> 
                                <td> <input type="radio" class="checkbox1" id="chk" name="check[]" value={creative} onClick={func1} /></td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

And the function `func1` simply logs the value

```
const func1 = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

When I'm using `value = {creative}`, the logged output is `[object Object]`.
I even tried using `value = {creative.ad_type, creative.ad_title}` but then it only logs the last value, in this case, `creative.ad_title`.
I want to log all the values of the `creative` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` to turn the object value to JSON format.

ex:

```
value{ JSON.stringify(creative) }
```

And then you try to get the value you need to parse it with `JSON.parse()`

```
const func1 = (e) => {
  console.log(JSON.parse(e.target.value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it worked. I need 1 more help, so in the function I don't want creative.id parameter, is there anyway to ignore that and get the rest 8 parameters?

Comment: You can create helper function `const removeKey = (key, { [key]: _, ...rest }) => rest; ` and use it as `removeKey('id', creative)`. Otherwise you would need to explicitly set property by property in a new object.

Comment: You are welcome, To do that you need to set the value of the object yourself.

value{ JSON.stringify({
      ad_type: creative.ad_type,
      ad_title: creative.ad_title,
      image_url: creative.image_url,
     video_thumbnail: creative.video_thumbnail,
      landing_url: creative.landing_url,
     placement: creative.placement,
    country: creative.country,
   dsp: creative.dsp 
}) }

Comment: Or as @Milos suggests to do a helper method to help you if you want repeatedly do that in other places in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the number/string as the value of the input field. you cannot directly pass an object as the value. so you have to convert the object to a string with  `JSON.stringify(creative)` which converts your object into a string. then after onChange, you will get the value and parse this value.

**another solution that I suggest to you:**

you already have the **creative** data. just pass **creative.id** as the value and onChange find that element from the **creative** array with the **event.target.value** which will be your id.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom readio input component

```
const RadioInput = ({ value, onClick }) => {
  return <input type="radio" value="" onClick={() => onClick(value)} />;
};
```

Use it. You also can pass other radio input properties to your custom component and attach them to your input.

```
<RadioInput
  onClick={func1}
  value={creative}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
  {
                    creatives.map(
                        creative =>
                        <tr key = {creative.id}>
                            <td>{creative.ad_type}</td>
                            <td>{creative.ad_title}</td>
                            <td>{creative.image_url}</td>
                            <td>{creative.video_thumbnail}</td>
                            <td>{creative.landing_url}</td>
                            <td>{creative.placement}</td>
                            <td>{creative.country}</td>
                            <td>{creative.dsp}</td> 
                            <td> <input type="radio" class="checkbox1" id="chk" name="check[]" value={creative} onClick={func1} /></td>
                        </tr>
                    )
                }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).